# Error in "GetSources" step in VSTS build for Git LFS Repository

Tags: git, build, azure-pipelines, git-lfs

I just created a brand new git + git lfs repository and added my sources to it in VSTS. However whenever I try to do a build I see the following message:

```
error: failed to push some objects to 'https://OAuth:********@*****.visualstudio.com/*****/_git/*****.git/info/lfs'
Git fetch failed with exit code: 2
```

[image: Git LFS error]

I have the following configuration setup in the VSTS Get Sources task:

[image: VSTS build configuration]

I've already tried to change the configuration and disabled Git LFS Checkout but no success.

Edit 1:
When I clone the command using git lfs clone  it works correctly as seen below (I ran this command on my Azure VM that is also running the VSTS agent):
[image: git lfs clone works]

Comment: Please check if files in LFS exist correctly by `git lfs clone <repo URL>`. And what if you set `Agent.Source.Git.Lfs` = `true` in variables Tab?

Comment: Hi Marina, I already did a clone manually and that worked fine :). Indeed by both the git lfs clone and the git clone commands. Setting the Agent.Source.Git.Lfs = true doesn't seem to make a difference either. I'll update my question with a screenshot of the correctly working git lfs clone command.

Comment: Did you use Hosted agent or private agent? You can try to build with the private agent which you execute `git lfs clone` successfully.

Comment: I used a private agent, so that's what I did.

Comment: Is build agent running as service? Try to change build service account to your account. (Local Service> double click agent service> Log on > specify account)

Comment: I checked what account it runs on, and it already runs on my local administrator account.